# where to find block 0 of flash memory in android?

Tags: android, storage, partition, flash-memory

I am reading android internals book.
There its mentioned that i can check my drive sectors and partitions by using the following command on adb with root
I tried to look for mmcblk0 block device and tried to see the octal dump. But I can't find mmcblk0.

```
>ls /dev/block
```

But I can't find mmcblk0 there but other blocks like loop0...sda..sdb.. sdb...ram etc.

So is there any command I can use to know my partitions with their starting and ending block number?

Comment: are you sure you run the command on your android device? the result looks like the command has been run on your host linux pc

Comment: @AlexP. I ran it from adb from ubuntu machine with root access

Comment: @SurjyaNarayanaPadhi I'm interested in this, what book is it? I would love to check it out as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic answer to this question. Kernel, drivers and hardware configuration are not part of Android and are not being provided by Google. These are parts of the [BSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_support_package) and are provided by hardware vendor. So the specific details up to each and every vendor.

For the learning purposes just pick another less obscure device which matches the book you are using more closely.